# Why I'm getting 'Error mapping GraphModel' error with neo4j OGM

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

## Inputs:

1. I am using a server cluster structure with 1 LEADER and 2 FOLLOWERS.
2. Nodes structure
   [image: node structure]

Save Payout method:

```java
@Override
@UseBookmark
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void addEmploymentPayout(EmploymentPayoutDTO payoutDto, String employmentId) {
    try {
        // Map
        var payout = dozerMapper.map(payoutDto, EmploymentPayout.class);

        // Save
        var employment = profileService.findEmploymentByUuid(employmentId);

        var container = employmentPayoutContainerRepository.getContainerIfExist(employmentId)
                                                           .orElse(new EmploymentPayoutContainer());
        container.setEmployment(employment);

        var payouts = Optional.ofNullable(container.getEmploymentPayouts())
                              .orElse(new ArrayList<>());
        payouts.add(payout);
        container.setEmploymentPayouts(payouts);
        employmentPayoutContainerRepository.save(container);

        // employmentPayout.setEmploymentPayoutContainer(container);
        // employmentPayoutRepository.save(payout);
        // employmentPayoutRepository.save(employmentPayout, 2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    }
}
```

Method `getAllPureEmploymentsByProfileId`:

```java
@Query("MATCH (p:Profile) WHERE p.uuid=$profileId "
    + "MATCH (p)-[:HAS_PROFILE_EMPLOYMENT_CONTAINER]->(pec:ProfileEmploymentContainer) "
    + "MATCH path = (pec)-[:USES_PROFILE_EMPLOYMENT]-(pe:ProfileEmployment) RETURN pec, path")
ProfileEmploymentContainer getAllPureEmploymentsByProfileId( @Param("profileId") String profileId);
```

## Description

After saving (adding) a new `EmploymentPayout` (`addEmploymentPayout`), when I try to load all or part of the path (`getAllPureEmploymentsByProfileId`), I get this error. But the error disappears after restarting the server.
Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Error mapping GraphModel; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SessionFactoryUtils.convertOgmAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:31)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.getAllPureEmploymentsByProfileId(Unknown Source)
    at com.infotemp.neo4j.service.impl.ProfileServiceImpl.getEmploymentsForUser(ProfileServiceImpl.java:7410)
    at com.infotemp.neo4j.service.impl.ProfileServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9ac11082.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at com.infotemp.neo4j.service.impl.ProfileServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$56efb754.getEmploymentsForUser(<generated>)
    at com.infotemp.neo4j.service.impl.VacationCompensationAccountServiceImpl.getProfileEmployments(VacationCompensationAccountServiceImpl.java:536)
    at com.infotemp.neo4j.service.impl.VacationCompensationAccountServiceImpl.getCurrentEmployment(VacationCompensationAccountServiceImpl.java:73)
    at com.infotemp.neo4j.service.impl.VacationCompensationAccountServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$18090ab5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at com.infotemp.neo4j.service.impl.VacationCompensationAccountServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5ea6899a.getCurrentEmployment(<generated>)
    at com.infotemp.controller.ProfileController.getVacationCompansation(ProfileController.java:2096)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapContentOf(GraphEntityMapper.java:164)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.lambda$map$2(GraphEntityMapper.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:117)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphRowModelMapper.map(GraphRowModelMapper.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.lambda$executeAndMap$1(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:165)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:590)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:564)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.executeAndMap(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:150)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:117)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.query(Neo4jSession.java:425)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.lambda$invoke$1(SharedSessionCreator.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invokeInTransaction(SharedSessionCreator.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedSessionCreator.java:123)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.execute(GraphQueryExecution.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.doExecute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.execute(AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Utils.coerceTypes(Utils.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.FieldInfo.write(FieldInfo.java:449)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.createRelationshipEntity(GraphEntityMapper.java:419)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapRelationshipEntity(GraphEntityMapper.java:354)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapRelationships(GraphEntityMapper.java:330)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapContentOf(GraphEntityMapper.java:158)
    ... 150 more
```

I tried to add these annotations but it didn't help:

- `@UseBookmark`
- `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)`

**UPD**

I don't have that problem with standalone (no clusters) Neoj4 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what caused this problem. It was the call of this asynchronous method:

```java
emailService.sendPayoutCreatedEmailAsync(employmentId, payout, userDetails); // fire-and-forget
```

The method above is called just after the `addEmploymentPayout` one.

This is a definition of this method which is called another non-ansync method - `sendPayoutCreatedEmail` (this method has calls to repository methods):

```java
@Override
public CompletableFuture<Void> sendPayoutCreatedEmailAsync(String employmentId, EmploymentPayoutDTO payout, InfotempUserDetails userDetails) {

    var future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        this.sendPayoutCreatedEmail(employmentId, payout, userDetails);
    });

    return future;
}
```

#### SOLUTION:

It works (don't know how, but it does) if you change the asynchronous method call to a call from a new thread. Like this:

```java
new Thread(() -> {
    emailService.sendPayoutCreatedEmail(employmentId, payout, userDetails);
}).start();
```